# Bootstrap 3 progress bar add counter time in Interval

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I'm trying to increment progress-bar current width from `setInterval` counter using button.

MUST: Everytime I click the button current count will add 2.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-danger"  role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Add Counter
</button>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function progress(){
    var count = 100;
    var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
        count--;
        if (count > 0){
            $('.progress-bar').css('width', count+'%');
        } else {
            clearInterval(counterBack);
        }

    }, 100);
}

progress();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/askingquestion/obt5d82c/8/)

Answer (score 0):

This may help to increment progress-bar current width from setInterval counter using button.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-danger"  role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Add Counter
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    function progress(){
        var count = 0;
        var counter = setInterval(function(){
            count++;
            if (count < 100){
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', count+'%');
            } else {
                clearInterval(counter);
            }

        }, 100);
    }
        progress();
});
```